# API Management & Best Practices

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api

Trying to get some expert opinion and direction:

We are exploring some of our RestAPIs by our customers to get data and build databases at their end.. Some use sql, some nosql datastores.

How should we design the endpoints? Large objects with embedded referenced objects or separate endpoints for separate objects? And what about references? Are there any best practices to keep in mind while we take a look at the schemas?

Examples: 
Movie has images 
Movie has similar movies 
Movies has cast members as well

Also, how can I go about evaluating if a new endpoint makes sense or embedding objects in existing endpoint is better?

Curious to hear some thoughts and reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental question is: will you always ask for full set of data (images, similar movies, cast, ...) or you want to have a choice to get only part of it? The second question is: how much the datasets overlap? (actor can play in >100 films and retrieving his info as part of each film info is pointless)

If you will always want to get it all, then go for large objects with embedded referenced objects (just remember to use compression). This approach should be more efficient if network bandwidth is a problem.

If you want to have more flexibility it will be better to go for separate endpoints. It will cause more network traffic. If you will choose this approach you should consider using some kind of cache.

On the other hand you can create hybrid that return basic info for `/movie` but extended data for `/movie?include=images,cast` and `/movie?include=all`.
But this will require more development work.

There also might be a forth option. Did you hear about GraphQL (https://graphql.org/)? It allows to define what data you want to retrieve.

Comment: Thank Irek. Yes ear I have explored GraphQL. The only thing I struggle to wrap my head around is that currently the APIs are used by customers to build databases at their end - so resource specific endpoints allow them to poll different objects and create the database quicker. With GraphQL, since there is one endpoint I am not sure if that will work as well. And more over if I want to update customers that something has updated on a particular resource, how do I do it with GraphQL.

Comment: If graphQL doesn't suits your needs I would go for side-loading pattern.